# Disable year in iOS HTML5 date picker

Tags: ios, html, datepicker

I suppose this question may be valid for other browsers and Operating Systems, but that's what I'm currently working on.

I'm building a website with a form that has a field for the user's birthday; I'm using the `date` input type but I don't really need the year to be there since the birthday recurs every year.

I've been googling around but I can't find anyone with a similar problem apparently and if anyone can help I'll be really grateful.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: The date input type is a browser implementation. Some browsers don't even have it. Consider using a jQuery plugin for date picking, most also have many configuration options such as disabling year.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be to use a normal input field and check with regular expressions if it's correct.